# ExtJs4 cell editing - modify edited value before save to store

Tags: extjs4

I'm editing a value in a grid and I need that edited value will be changed before saving to store. Tried to modify the value by using event [edit](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/extjs-build/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-edit) and event validateedit.
But after saving changes don't save to the store.

```
listeners: {
    edit: function(editor, e, eOpts) {
        e.value = e.value + ' some aditional changes'; //this doesn't saved
    },
    validateedit: function(editor, e, eOpts) {
        e.value = e.value + ' some aditional changes one more attempt'; //this doesn't saved also
    }
}
```

Can I modify it someway?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Must be modifyed `e.record.data` instead of `e.value`:

```
edit: function(editor, e, eOpts) {
    e.record.data[e.field] = e.value + ' some aditional changes'; //this works
}
```

Both `validateedit` and `edit` events works.